# what's the necessity of "else" in Python exception handling?

Tags: python, exception

I am having trouble understanding the following control flow.

```
try:
    # normal execution block
except A:
    # handle exception A
except B:
    # handle exception B
except:
    # handle other exceptions
else:
    # if no exceptions, go here
finally:
    # always do this
```

I don't understand the purpose of the a `else` in this context. I am coming from Java where there is no `else` clause for handling exceptions.

If I have something to write in the `else` part, I would assume that I can directly write it outside of the exception handling part either.

So, whats the necessity of the `else` clause in Python exception handling?

Comment: I think you mean "handler," not "handle." "Handler" is the noun for a thing that handles something. "Handle" (in this sense) is a verb. (There's also a "handle" noun, but it's unrelated.)

Comment: thanks!sorry for my fault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have something to write in else clause,I can directly write outside of the exception handle part either.

No.

```
def with_else(x):    
    try:
        int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print('that did not work')
    else:
        print('that worked!')

def without_else(x):    
    try:
        int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print('that did not work')

    print('that worked!')
```

Demo:

```
>>> with_else(1)                                                                                                       
that worked!
>>> without_else(1)                                                                                                    
that worked!
>>> with_else('foo')                                                                                                   
that did not work
>>> without_else('foo')                                                                                                
that did not work
that worked!
```

Comment: but there's another question,why can't we just move the  `else ` clause to the `try`part?

Comment: @user8394497 because that code might throw an exception itself you might want to handle differently (or not handle at all).

Answer (score 0):

```
processing = True

try:
    x = might_raise_a_key_error()
    # a
except KeyError:
    ...
else:
    # b
finally:
    processing = False

# c
```

If you have a piece of code which 1) depends on `x`, 2) you don’t want handled by `except KeyError`, but 3) you do want covered by the `finally` clause, do you put it in `# a`, `# b` or `# c`?

Answer: `# b`.

Comment: Thanks but could you be more specific?

Comment: About what in particular?

Comment: like a example of "processing = True" part

Comment: English is not my first language,sorry about my expression,I still cant figure a circumstance about your description

Comment: It’s just an example of something you might do in a `finally`. The point is, if you put code at `# a`, and it raises a `KeyError`, it’ll get handled, and you might not want that. If you put it at `# c` instead, the `finally` clause will happen first, and you might not want that.

Comment: sorry,it's me again,do you mean :even X get a `KeyError`,but I still want it handled by the `except` part?

Comment: and I got confused again,can we just merge the `else` part with the `try` part? In Java,there's no `else`

Comment: I checked your answer again,and I think put the code in #a and #b will get the same result

Comment: Again, if `# b` might also raise an exception, **and you don’t want that to be caught by `except`,** you put it in `else`.